# Make column of width 9 fill entire width if no other columns

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

Using Foundation 6, I have a `large-3 column` to the left of a `large-9 column`. This is great, except under certain circumstances the `large-3 column` may not be there. In this case I would like the remaining column to fill the entirety of the row, i.e. behave as if it was a `large-12` column instead. I feel like this sort of thing should be supported natively by Foundation somehow, but couldn't see anything about it in the docs, and am at a loss as to how I'd achieve it manually.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR; - Foundation doesn't supports this feature, but I've read your question and there are some possible solutions:

1. what controls the `large-3 columns`'s presence? if it's via some sort of script / query (PHP/Python) you can echo the relevant div. for example:

   ```
   if (some_condition === true) {
       echo '<div class="large-3 columns">...</div>';
       echo '<div class="large-9 columns">...</div>';
   } else {
       echo '<div class="large-12 columns">...</div>';
   }
   ```
2. if you need to hide it in certain resolutions you can use the grid's built in functionality:

   ```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="large-3 show-for-large columns"><!-- ... --></div>
     <div class="large-9 medium-12 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. you can remove / add the div via jQuery's `remove()` method:

   ```
   $( ".large-3" ).remove();
   ```

I hope that it helped. anyway, feel free to add code so we can assist more.